# How to find the correct navigation course by gps navigation with Arduino?

Tags: arduino-mega, gps

I have a problem for about days ago and here it is :

I have an RC plane and wanna make it autonomous via GPS navigation by Arduino

I have an Arduino Mage 2560 onboard connected to a GPS Ublox-Neo-M8N (GPS module) and there is the problem

I want my RC-Plane to read it's position and go to waypoints

The Coordinates of  two waypoints  are defined before on a matrix variable like this example :

```
a [1] [3] =
{
    {38.884675, -116.671035, 
     245}
};

b [1] [3] =
{
    {38.725019, -116.580951, 
     1180}
};

( 1st is Latitude, 2nd is Longitude and 3rd is height)
```

So i want my Arduino to read it's current position from gps module's data and calculate the correct Azimuth (correct horizontal angle) and the correct pitch angle (vertical angle) to navigate my plane to the waypoints

and remember, when it reaches to the waypoint "a" with a few error (miss distance = 4 meters), it should be able to ignore navigation to the waypoint of variable "a" and then, navigate to waypoint "b"

I WAND THE EXACT COMMAND FROM ANY LIBRARY TO CALCULATE THOSE TWO ANGLE FOR NAVIGATION (azimuth direction angle and pitch angle to navigate RC-Plane from everywhere o the waypoints

Comment: The track (course over ground) is typically calculated by the GPS receiver and included in the data it sends. So you do not need to calculate anything there.

Comment: The "navigation" part of your question is complex, though. Particularly since your plane does not have 6 degrees of freedom (like a drone) calculating a path to a waypoint includes a curve.

Comment: very good question, however it is about navigation, not about Arduino, so it is off topic here ... downvote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The computation is not difficult. Since your drone is unlikely to travel
for thousands of kilometers, you can assume the Earth is locally flat,
and the latitude and longitude are an orthogonal coordinate system.
First, compute the vector to the next waypoint in Cartesian coordinates
(dx, dy, dz):

```cpp
// Defined at global scope.
const float radians_per_degree = M_PI / 180;
const float degrees_per_radians = 180 / M_PI;
const float meters_per_degree = 1e7 / 90;

// For every reading of the GPS:
float dx = (waypoint.longitude - current.longitude) * meters_per_degree
         * cos(current.latitude * radians_per_degree);
float dy = (waypoint.latitude - current.latitude) * meters_per_degree;
float dz = waypoint.height - current.height;
```

Then, from this vector you can get the required angles:

```cpp
float azimuth = atan2(dx, dy) * degrees_per_radians;
float pitch_angle = atan(dz/sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)) * degrees_per_radians;
```

Note that the approximation breaks down if the drone has to travel for a
distance that is a significant fraction of the distance to the closest
pole. Note also that the approximation errors are inconsequential if you
periodically update your estimate of azimuth and pitch angle: the errors
will be corrected along the way as the drone gets closer and closer to
the waypoint.

**Edit**: timemage posted a very interesting comment, and I would want
to further expand on the precision issue. The AVR floating point support
is indeed limited to single precision. For latitudes and longitudes in
the range shown in the question, the numerical resolution (formally, the
[unit in the last place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)) is (3.81×10<sup>−6</sup>)° for the latitude
and (7.63×10<sup>−6</sup>)° for the longitude. This translates to about
42 cm and 66 cm respectively on the surface of the Earth. It
may be just good enough to hit the waypoint to within 4 m.

You could increase the resolution by storing the latitude and longitude
in microdegrees, as 32-bit integers. This should be easy if the GPS
always gives 6 digits after the decimal point: just ignore that
decimal point. Then, once the quantities
`waypoint.longitude - current.longitude`
and `waypoint.latitude - current.latitude` are computed, you can safely
use floating point for the rest of the computations.

Comment: I was 80% of the way through writing something like this only with TinyGPSPlus when the phone rang, after which this was posted. So, I'll just mention here that if they're being literal about wanting a library, that one will do the course and distance part (which is probably haversine based). The pitch I'd synthesized in pretty much exact same way as this. The only other difference of note I had in mine is just that the user says they're using an Mega, so AVR, so only single precision float is available which is accurate to about 6 decimal places, so they should expect errors at close range.

Comment: @timemage: Thanks for this very relevant comment. I edited my answer to address the accuracy issue.

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, he has a wing-type RC plane, not a drone. This can't just move in a specific direction.

Comment: @PMF, They asked how to calculate correct azimuth and pitch angle from one coordinate to another. It's true that they didn't use the word "drone." I'm just guessing it's used in the answer because ¨drone" can be taken to mean (semi-)autonomous (which makes sense given the question) vs say "multi-rotor" (implying ability change direction with ease). The OP didn't seem to put any real emphasize on it being a fixed wing craft and the need to plan motion in connection with it being a "RC plane." Maybe the way-points are far enough apart for this to be of real concern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the main question is : Is there any Arduino's Library (mention the library) which can calculate this ?

Comment: You mentioned in the answer that the accuracy is 44 cm and 66 cm. Can you describe it more? For example this accuracy is for each kilometer? If not how much is the accuracy for 5 kilometers?

Comment: @Hamid'Smith'Salehi: There may be a library that does this, but I am not aware of any. Also, I do not understand what you mean by “accuracy for each kilometer”. Did you read the Wikipedia article _Unit in the last place_?

Comment: I mean, using this calcution has some error because we assumed that earth is flat, so how much is error in every kilometer distance?

Comment: And what is M_PI ?

Comment: @Hamid'Smith'Salehi: The approximation error would be quite complex to compute, and depend on the exact start and end points of the path. Not anything as simple as an “error per kilometer”. If you get GPS updates periodically, the approximation error will only make the path slightly curved, instead of being a straight line (or rather, a great circle). The error created by wind is likely to be many orders of magnitude larger. `M_PI` is π (pi).

Comment: M_PI = π =3.14259....  You could divide the 44 and 66cm resolution of each endpoint by the number of kilometers of distance between the two points if you want.  The inaccuracy of using the flat-earth approximation versus calculating a great circle is that the great circle course doesn't have a constant azimuth that the flat-earth approximation would.  How far are your waypoints from each other?

Comment: Thanks for your response.Maximum distance is 5 kilometers

Comment: I tested it by an example : start point is 52.70594, 13.37933 altitude = 67 meters and the waypoint is : 52.71957, 1338046 altitude is 64 and the result was : azimuth = 87.124287071904 and the pitch angle = -0.113355534.....  . The pich angle seems to be true but i know that the waypoint is in the north of the start point so the azimuth must be something like 0 (less or more). What is the problem?

Comment: i replaced latitude with longitude and also longitude with latitude in the formula, and it seemed is working properly. Can you check it please?

Comment: @Hamid'Smith'Salehi: You are right. In order for the north to be at 0°, the azimuth must be computed as `atan2(dx, dy)`. I edited the code in my answer.